# Как заменить множество if

Tags: php

Есть таблица в БД, где не все поля заполнены. Нужно выводить только те, в которых значение не null.

Решил вот таким образом, но множество if, код не универсальный получился

```
if($types->priceType != null)
        echo 'Тип: '.$types->priceType->name.'<br>';
    if($types->course != null)
        echo 'Тип курс: '.$types->course->name.'<br>';
    if($types->count_room != null)
        echo 'Количество комнат: '.$types->count_room.'<br>';
    if($types->count_meter != null)
        echo 'Количество метров: '.$types->count_meter.'<br>';
    if($types->is_repair != null)
        echo 'С ремонтом'.'<br>';
    if($types->is_new_building_id != null)
        echo 'Новое здание: '.$types->is_new_building_id.'<br>';
    if($types->count_hundredth != null)
        echo 'Количество соток: '.$types->count_hundredth.'<br>';
    if($types->type_realty_id != null)
        echo 'Тип недвижимости: '.$types->type_realty_id.'<br>';
```

Скажите, можно ли каким-то образом переписать , чтобы не было повторений с if ??

Comment: Да я сразу не заметил что для каждого поля у вас свое название, поэтому думаю тут ничего делать не надо и оставить все как есть,  все равно из за названий нужно будет в каком то месте прописывать вывод с условием. Уменьшите количество кода здесь, увеличите в другом месте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пару методов наваять:

1) вернет поле объекта по имени

```
function returnObj($obj, $field) {
    return $obj->{$field};
}
```

2) вернет значение поля, если дать на вход объект, поле для проверки и массив полей, до которого нужно добраться. Что-то типа такого:

```
function getValue2($myObj, $fieldCheck, $fieldsGet) {
    if ($myObj->$fieldCheck != null) {
        $obj = $myObj;
        foreach ($fieldsGet as $val) {
            if ($obj->{$val} != null) {
                $obj = returnObj($obj, $val);
            }
        }

        return $obj;
    }       
}
```

В итоге, допустим есть классы

```
class Test {

    public $pole = 666;
    public $priceTypes = null;  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->priceTypes = new Price();
    }
}

class Price {
    public $name = 999;
}
```

тогда будет что-то типа такого:

```
$test = new Test();
echo getValue2($test, 'priceTypes', ['priceTypes', 'name']);
```

---

или если нет цепочки полей, то простой метод

```
function getValue($testy, $field) {
    if ($testy->$field != null)
        return $testy->{$field};
}
```

и получение:

```
$test = new Test();
echo getValue($test, 'pole');
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1

```
echo $types->priceType?'Тип: '.$types->priceType->name.'<br>':'';
echo $types->course->name?'Тип курс: '.$types->course->name.'<br>':'';
```

и т.д.

Вариант 2

Добавить в класс объекта $types, например такие, методы

```
public function priceType(){
    return $this->priceType?'Тип: '.$types->priceType->name.'<br>':'';
}
```

А в основном коде выводить так

```
echo $types->priceType();
```

И вариантов таких - вагон и маленькая тележка.

Comment: тогда уж `getPriceType`... типа геттер

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это не геттер, от слова совсем. Тут скорее подошло бы что-то типа getPriceTypePrintableText, но я решил не плодить излишних сущностей.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не копировать if, можно перебрать, объект с помощью цикла foreach, php под рукой нет, на память по моему так:

```
   foreach ($types as $key => $value) {

       if ($value != null)
            echo "$key: ".$value.'<br>';
   }
```

Если я ошибся напишите пожалуйста, я удалю ответ.

Comment: Перебрать то можно, но 1) Не факт, что нужны все свойства объекта, 2)  Порядок вывода важен, 3) Текст для каждого свойства свой, 4) Некоторые свойства сами являются объектами и печатать нужно их свойства - $types->course->name, $types->count_meter

Comment: Согласен что не решена проблема с тем, что названия для всех свойств разные должны быть, но создавая для каждого echo отдельный метод, вы вопроса не решаете, лучше уж просто оставить как у него, понятнее и кода меньше. Про остальные требования, откуда они взялись, вопрос задавал другой пользователь?

Comment: Остальные требования видны из кода, приведенного в вопросе (ну кроме порядка - это я додумал). По поводу отдельных методов, то принцип единственной ответственности еще никто не отменял, а тут все же ооп.

Comment: То что ОПП нужно на больших проектах, спору нет (возможно у него всего 2-3 страницы на сайте), но я имел ввиду что делая методы вы не отвечаете на вопрос как ему не писать для каждого свойства if. 8 конструкций if в одном месте = по 1 конструкции if в 8 местах.  В его примере лучше не думать все оставить как есть.